# Elasticsearch with range and exists filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch query to get every products within a set range. I would like to add a filter to select only documents which have the attribute "products". My tests with must exists had always error.

```
/zipcodes_at/zipcode/_search

{
  "_source": [
    "products"
  ],
  "filter": {
    "geo_distance": {
      "distance": "100km",
      "location": {
        "lat": 48.232361,
        "lon": 16.324659
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 48.232361,
          "lon": 16.324695

        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the query you tried with `must/exists`?

Comment: Oh I haven't save them. Always had syntax errors and I guess they were completly wrong.

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: "version" : {
    "number" : "2.0.0",
    "lucene_version" : "5.2.1"
  },

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
POST /zipcodes_at/zipcode/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "products"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "products"
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "100km",
            "location": {
              "lat": 48.232361,
              "lon": 16.324659
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 48.232361,
          "lon": 16.324695
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should must use bool filter , and combine geo distance filter along with exist filter.

```
{
    "_source": ["products"],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "products"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance_range": {
                            "from": 0,
                            "to": 100,
                            "distance_unit": "km",
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 40.73,
                                "lon": -74.1
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "_geo_distance": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 48.232361,
                "lon": 16.324695

            },
            "order": "asc",
            "unit": "km",
            "distance_type": "plane"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Note that [`filtered/filter` is deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_filtered_literal_query_and_literal_query_literal_filter_deprecated) in ES 2.x, it's better to use `bool/filter` instead.

Comment: k. i am still running 1.7.2 on production, planning to upgrade soon.Thanks for pointing, will go through release notes before upgrading.